# Почему обрезается сообщение при отправке через vk api/curl (PHP)?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl

Приветствую. Вот мой код отправки сообщения через vk API + curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(['peer_id'=>$peer_id, 'message'=>$message, 'v'=>$v, 'access_token'=>$access_token]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

При отправке больших сообщений (4,5-5 тыс. символов) мне приходит лишь обрезанное сообщение, при этом vk не возвращает никаких ошибок. Я получаю 4090 символов (хотя раньше и меньше приходило, не всегда 4090). Пробовал отправить своё сообщение через сайт вк - всё работает нормально и не обрезается. В документации ничего про ограничение объема текста не говорится. В чем моя проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задал вопрос техподдержке ВКонтакте и получил такой ответ:

> Максимальная длина личного сообщения — 4096 символов. Соответственно и параметр message больше не примет.

Интересно, что в документации ничего про это не говорится.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде нет ошибок — он работает корректно, хотя я бы убрал `http_build_query()`, т.к. параметр `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` [прекрасно принимает обычные ассоциативные массивы](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Вероятнее всего, проблема обрезания строки находится где-то выше. Подозреваю, что вы через AJAX передаете в ваш скрипт GET-запросом содержимое переменной `$message`, из-за чего она обрезается в силу [ограничений длины GET-запроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request). Если я прав, то просто поменяйте метод с GET на POST и все заработает.

Comment: Нет, строка `$message` генерируется в самом скрипте, поэтому проблема не в этом...